unreadable metadata in browers->view page source
i m using generateMetadata() across multiple components to generate metadata.
example: below is the code for my faqpage.tsx
import { generateMeta } from "@/components/common/header/Meta";
import FaqPageModule from "@/modules/(frontend)/faq/faqPageModule";
import { apiGetFaq } from "@/modules/(frontend)/home/endpoint/homepage/getFaq";
import React from "react";

const fetchFaq = async () => {
  const response = await apiGetFaq();
  return response?.data?.data.rows;
};
const FaqPage = async () => {
  const faq = await fetchFaq();
  return <FaqPageModule faq={faq} />;
};

export async function generateMetadata(params: any) {
  const title = "Frequently Asked Questions - JobAxle";
  const metaKeyword = "";
  const metaDescription =
    "Find answers to the most frequently asked questions about JobAxle.";
  const ogTitle = "Frequently Asked Questions - JobAxle";
  const ogDescription =
    "Find answers to the most frequently asked questions about JobAxle.";
  const ogUrl = "https://www.jobaxle.com/faq";
  const ogType = "website";
  const siteName = "JobAxle";
  const ogImage =
    "https://jobaxle.com/uploads/company/logo/c89bf7a5dfd3ef41b7300769c616b133.png";
  const twitterCreator = "@AxleJob";
  const twitterCard = "summary_large_image";

  return generateMeta(
    title,
    metaKeyword,
    metaDescription,
    ogTitle,
    ogDescription,
    ogUrl,
    ogType,
    siteName,
    ogImage,
    twitterCreator,
    twitterCard
  );
}

export default FaqPage;

the generateMeta function is as:
interface MetaProps {
  title: string;
  description?: string;
  url?: string;
  image?: string;
}
export async function generateMeta(
  title: any,
  metaKeyword: any,
  metaDescription: any,
  ogTitle: any,
  ogDescription: any,
  ogUrl: any,
  ogType: any,
  siteName: any,
  ogImage: any,
  twitterCreator: any,
  twitterCard: any
) {
  return {
    title: `${title}`,
    keywords: `${metaKeyword}`, // You can make this dynamic as well if needed
    description: `${metaDescription}`,
    openGraph: {
      title: `${ogTitle}`,
      description: `${ogDescription}`,
      url: `${ogUrl}`,
      siteName: `${siteName}`,
      images: [
        {
          url: `${ogImage}`, // Must be an absolute URL
        },
      ],

      twitter: {
        title: `${ogTitle}`,
        description: `${ogDescription}`,
        site: `${siteName}`,
        creator: `${twitterCreator}`,
        images: [`${ogImage}`],
        card: `${twitterCard}`,
      },
      locale: "en_US",
      type: `${ogType}`,
    },
  };
}


now when i go to my website and then goto "view page source", then i get the metadata as below, which is quite unreadable:

however i want it to be a bit readable, similar to like:

is there any way i can do fix this in next.js ?
i m tried quite a few things. first i tried using "pretty" library to change the format of html output, then in my generateMeta function, i tried by changing the code as:
export async function generateMeta(
  title,
  metaKeyword,
  metaDescription,
  ogTitle,
  ogDescription,
  ogUrl,
  ogType,
  siteName,
  ogImage,
  twitterCreator,
  twitterCard
) {
  return `
    <title>${title}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="${metaDescription}" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="${metaKeyword}" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="${ogTitle}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="${ogDescription}" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="${ogUrl}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="${ogImage}" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="${ogType}" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="${siteName}" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="${twitterCard}" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="${twitterCreator}" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="${ogTitle}" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="${ogDescription}" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="${ogImage}" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="${siteName}" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="${ogUrl}" />
  `;
}


this didn't even displayed the metadata information in the browser
